# QuantLib C++: Friendship dilemma between derived class from PiecewiseYieldCurve and Bootstrap class

Tags: programming, quantlib

I derived a class template, `OISCurve<Traits,Interpolator,Bootstrap>`, from `PiecewiseYieldCurve<Traits,Interpolator,Bootstrap>`. The functionality provided by the class works fine as long as i use the default class `IterativeBootstrap` as the third template parameter.

On the other side I have implemented a bootstrap algorithm as the `calculate()` method of a new class, `OISBootstrap`. The implementation follows the structure of the default class `IterativeBootstrap`.

I have also added in my derived class the following friend class as done in the declaration of `PiecewiseYieldCurve<Traits,Interpolator,Bootstrap>`:

```
friend class Bootstrap <PiecewiseYieldCurve<Traits, Interpolator, Bootstrap>>;
```

`OISBootstrap` needs in fact access to private members of `OISCurve`, but also to private members of `PiecewiseYieldCurve` and to its derived members as well.

Unfortunately I'm still getting compiling errors saying that `OISBootstrap` cannot access private/protected members of the classes `OISCurve` derives from, like `PiecewiseYieldCurve`, `InterpolatedCurve` and `TermStructure`.

**Question:** The declaration of friendship in `PiecewiseYieldCurve` shouldn't suffice to give access to `OISBootstrap` as well? (of course not since i'm getting compiling erros but i hope i made my point)

Thanks for the help.

## EDIT

**OISCurve.h**

```
template <class Traits, class Interpolator,
    template <class> class Bootstrap = IterativeBootstrap>
class OISCurve : public PiecewiseYieldCurve < Traits, Interpolator, Bootstrap >
{
public:

    OISCurve(
        Natural settlementDays,
        const Calendar& calendar,
        const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Quote>>& quotes,
        const DayCounter& dayCounter,
        Real accuracy,
        const Interpolator& i = Interpolator(),
        const Bootstrap<PiecewiseYieldCurve<Traits, Interpolator, Bootstrap>>& bootstrap = Bootstrap<PiecewiseYieldCurve<Traits, Interpolator, Bootstrap>>());

    friend std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper>> constructRateHelpers(const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Quote>>& quotes);
}
```

**OISBootstrap**

```
template<class Curve>
class OISBootstrap
{
protected:
    typedef typename Curve::traits_type Traits;
    typedef typename Curve::interpolator_type Interpolator;

public:
    OISBootstrap();
    void setup(Curve* ts);
    virtual void calculate() const;
    virtual ~OISBootstrap();

protected:
    void initialize() const;
    void setupHelpers() const;
    Curve* ts_;
    Size n_;
    mutable bool initialized_, validCurve_;
    mutable Size firstAliveHelper_, alive_;
    mutable std::vector<Real> previousData_;
};
```

**Instantiation**

```
boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> oisCurve( new
            OISCurve<Discount, LogLinear, OISBootstrap>(2, TARGET(), _quotes, Actual360(), 1.0e-12));
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration of the class and how you instantiate it? The template instantiation is tricky, and there are a lot of things that might cause this.

Comment: @Luigi thanks for the help. I have posted the code.

Comment: You said you had a declaration `friend class Bootstrap <...>;` in your derived class, but I don't see it. Which is correct, the question or the code?

Comment: Sorry for that. I deleted it since OISBootstrap was not accessing any private members of OISCurve. I'm still getting the same compiling errors as before after this modification.

Comment: With your declarations, I'm able to access protected members of the base classes. What members are you trying to access, and from what method? Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I thought it was not important but reading more about friendship it became clear that I had omitted an important fact. Actually `OISBootstrap` is a derived class, the base class implemented all methods except the `calculate()` method which was implemented in `OISBootstrap`.  Implementing all the methods in OISBoostrap gets rid of the compiler errors as you would expect. I will read more about friendship because it would be handy to keep the base class. To answer your question, I'm using MSVC. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion.